# copy RichTextBox content and paste to Hotmail, Yahoo like Rich Text Editor

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, richtextbox

in my vb.net application i want to copy RichTextBox1 's contents and paste to

Hotmail, Yahoo kind of Rich Text Editor.

this is what i did until now but it only copy and paste text only not contains image and format.

```
RichTextBox1.LoadFile("test.rtf")
' Get the text from your rich text box
Dim textContents As String = RichTextBox1.Rtf
' Copy the text to the clipboard
Clipboard.SetText(textContents, TextDataFormat.Rtf)  
RichTextBox1.Copy() 
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("rtetext").InnerText = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Rtf)
```

first time i thought it not difficult problem but now i feel this is not simple problem.

i referenced and searched much in google but only can copy and paste text .

any help much appreciate

Comment: Can you try `DataFormats.Rtf` instead of `TextDataFormat.Rtf`? Of course it won't work if the receiver doesn't really expect Rtf but say Html formatted text..

Comment: i tested  but it not work,    RichTextBox1.LoadFile("image/test.rtf")

                            Clipboard.Clear()

                            Dim data As New DataObject()
                            data.SetData(DataFormats.Text, RichTextBox1.SelectedText)
                            data.SetData(DataFormats.Rtf, RichTextBox1.SelectedRtf)

                            Clipboard.SetDataObject(data)
                      
                            WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("rtetext").InnerText = Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Rtf)

Comment: populated result is {\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg949\deff0\deflang1033\deflangfe1042\deftab800{\info{\horzdoc}{\*\lchars $([\'5c\'7b\'a1\'cc\'a1\'cd\'a1\'ae\'a1\'b0\'a1\'b4\'a1\'b6\'a1\'b8\'a1\'ba\'a1\'bc\'a1\'b2\'a3\'a4\'a3\'a8\'a3\'db\'a3\'fb\'a1\'cc\'a1\'cd\'a3\'dc}{\*\fchars !%),.:\'3b?]\'7d\'a1\'cb\'a1\'c6\'a1\'af\'a1\'b1\'a1\'c7\'a1\'c8\'a1\'c9\'a1\'b5\'a1\'b7\'a1\'b9\'a1\'bb\'a1\'bd\'a1\'b3\'a3\'a1\'a3\'a5\'a3\'a9\'a3\'ac\'a3\'ae\'a3\'ba\'a3\'bb\'a3\'bf\'a3\'dd\'a3\'fd\'a1\'cb}}
\uc1 }

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember the exact details for how to do this, but hopefully this helps.

Firstly, you're using both `RichTextBox.Copy` and `Clipboard.SetText` which seems redundant.
Secondly, the use of `ClipBoard.SetText` implies that you're only copying the text, if you want to get all the data I think you need to look at [Clipboard.SetDataObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b8kt5z4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: i checked this method but unfortunetly it also only can copy text. thanks

Comment: @softfx No, that's incorrect. You can definitely use it to copy other data than text. I'm not sure if you'll be able to do exactly what you want, but you can use it to copy various kinds of data, here's a MSDN page with an example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/637ys738%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: RichTextBox1.LoadFile("test.rtf")
Clipboard.SetDataObject(RichTextBox1.Text, False)
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("rtetext").InnerText = Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Rtf)    i tried this code but only text and format can copy and paste but couldn't copy and paste image.

Comment: @softfx That's not anything like the code in the example on the page I mentioned though. Go to the page mentioned in my previous comment and then scroll down until you see the section called `To add data to the Clipboard in multiple formats`. This example shows how to add an object rather than just text.